# sqlite3 "OperationalError: near "(": syntax error" python

Tags: python, sqlite

simply put i am trying to make a sql database table and input data into it. I have it working in a simpler way, but when I put it into my script it results in this error. I'm hoping its something simple I missed. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('Data1.db')

c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Data_Output6
         (date text, output6MV real)''') 

Averages_norm = []

for i, x in enumerate(Averages):
    Averages_norm.append(x*output_factor)
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Data_Output6 VALUES (%r,%r)" %(xdates[i],Averages_norm[-1]))
conn.commit()
```

results in the error:

```
57     for i, x in enumerate(Averages):
58         Averages_norm.append(x*output_factor)
---> 59         c.execute("INSERT INTO Data_Output6 VALUES (%r,%r)"%(xdates[i],Averages_norm[-1]))
60     conn.commit()
61
```

OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: So what data do you have in `xdates`?

Comment: Also, why are you using string interpolation instead of SQL parameters?

Comment: Try printing the statement before executing it. I'm sure you'll immediately spot the error.

Comment: You're inviting Booby Tables to tea... http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply put, let the DB API do that formatting:

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Data_Output6 VALUES (?, ?)", (xdates[i], Averages_norm[-1]))
```

And refer to the documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html where is mentioned:

> Instead, use the DB-API’s parameter substitution.

Comment: Thanks, that has really helped. I guess im sticking too much to what I know instead of getting to know the packages im using!