# SQL query runs in database but shows error in python Program

Tags: python, sql, syntax-error

I have a problem where SQL query runs without error in database(using Db browser), but when I run it in my python program it gives me an error.
The following is the query:

```
c.execute("SELECT Date, Details, SUM((Debit) - (Credit)) OVER (ORDER by Date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS balance FROM maindata WHERE Details =?' ORDER BY Date", pg)
```

It gives me this error-:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257826/sqlite3-operationalerror-near-syntax-error-python

Comment: `WHERE Details =?'` This symbol `'` after the `?` looks strange

Comment: Tried both above answers but still not solved, Thank you.

Comment: Remove `'` charactet from SQL, Also check whether `pg` parameter is a tuple or a list, if none of them (but for example a number or a string), then use `c.execute(".....", (pg,) )`

Comment: I tried the above method but still getting the same error, I tried writing the query in 4 lines and the error is coming in (pg, )  )